# Convert string byte array to Double

Tags: android

I have a String representation of Byte array recieved from a server, which looks like this.

```
"?Ëê%ÁS`?ãÃ¹/ŒPü?ÛlÅç`ÔÀ?èï0;D^?ÙÄjh#í´"
```

these are array of double values.

At the client side, client is android phone i'm not able to get the proper values. The proper double values are :

```
0.21534, 0.617642, 0.428514, 0.779198 and 0.402613.
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert byte array from double by below code...

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static byte[] toByteArray(double value) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
   ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
   return bytes;
}
```

& double form byte array by below code...

```
public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
   return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have:

```
String s="?Ëê%ÁS`?ãÃ¹/ŒPü?ÛlÅç`ÔÀ?èï0;D^?ÙÄjh#í´";
Double d;
```

Convert it by:

```
d = new Double(s);
```

Comment: I assume your last line accidentally switched the variable names?

Comment: then can you put some sample from your code to make it more clear.

Comment: i have not done any coding yet. I just used a basic TCP client example in order to check whether i recieve data from server or not. But got stuck with the above problem, So not able to go forward. I wanted how get back the double values